# strange Python syntax error with dict in 2.7 but not in 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I came across a blog post about [a strange python syntax error](http://blog.tplus1.com/blog/2013/06/28/obscure-python-syntax-error/). The code is below:

```
d1 = dict(
user_id=99,
display_name='Matt Wilson',)
print(d1)

d2 = dict(
email_address='matt@tplus1.com',
**d1,)
print(d2)
```

This runs fine on Python 3.5.2 but not 2.7.3. Here is the 2.7.3 complaining:

```
In [2]: d2 = dict(
   ...: email_address='matt@tplus1.com',
   ...: **d1,)
   ...: print(d2)
  File "<ipython-input-2-6036d3108b1d>", line 3
    **d1,)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Remove the last comma `,` after `d2 = dict(
email_address='matt@tplus1.com',
**d1,)`

Comment: Yes, this is an acknowledged bug in Python 2 and 3 up to 3.4, fixed in 3.5 and newer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , thanks for the response but can you provide me with the bug link? thanks a lot

Comment: I just read the linked question. Thanks